# Fancybox, setTimeout not working in a page after redirection

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fancybox-2

First at all, sorry for my question, I am new to jQuery and Javascript in general. I found in this page a nice code that works very well in my offline tests, and also works in the online site, but not for the specific page I want it to be loaded. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {

$.fancybox({
    'width'             : 292,
    'height'            : 62,
    'autoScale'         : true,
    'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'openEffect'        : 'fade',
    'closeEffect'       : 'elastic',
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'href'              : "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox..."
});
}, 5000);   
</script>
```

I put this code in the Head section, after loading all the required JS and CSS files. As said, it works fine everywhere except where I would like to have it. The reason for that is probably because that page is the result of a redirection. I mean: page A redirects to Page B, and I put the code in Page B. If the code were in Page A, it would have worked fine, but unfortunatelly I need it in Page B.

The reason I am using setTimeout is because it is the easiest code I found anywhere to load the popup fancybox once the page has finished loading; one does not need to add a reference to the iframe in the body section, and it is really easy to define the size of the box.

Could please somebody help me with it?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `setTimeout` and try encasing your code in `Document Ready handler`

```
<html>
   <head>
      // Your css files come here
   </head>
   <body>
       // You main HTML
      <script dependencies> go here  .. 
      <script  jquery
      <script fancybox plugin
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                'width'             : 292,
                'height'            : 62,
                'autoScale'         : true,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
                'openEffect'        : 'fade',
                'closeEffect'       : 'elastic',
                'type'              : 'iframe',
                'href'              : "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox..."
            });
        });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or place it at the bottom of the page, which makes the DOM be ready faster.

Comment: Right.. That should be the place where the placement of scripts is recommended

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I am really a newbe with Javascript. Could it please be possible to have a little more detail example of what you mean?

Comment: `DOM` handler fires after the document is ready, so you have the elements available on the page. It is always a good idea to place the script tags to just before the closing tag of body, so that there will be no delay when the document is rendered

Comment: And how I call this handler? Should I let the other part of the script on the <head> section? I would really appreciate an example. Many thanks again!

Comment: I have posted a rough example of how I was suggesting.. The Ready handler will be automatically invoked. You need not trigger anything for that to happen

Comment: Many thanks again. I tested the code offline and it works very well, unfortunatelly it happens the same as with the last code, for an unknown reason it is not working. It should have something to do with the redirection, because I could not imagen any other.